# Remove Chapter title from header on all pages, latex book class

Tags: latex

Edited to include a reproducible example.

So, I've found a number of people asking about how to add the chapter title from the header of subsequent pages but I need the opposite. I'm using fancy header but need everything except the page number removed from the header (the page needs to be at the top right of every page). The code I'm using removes the header from the first page of each chapter, but every subsequent page has the chapter name in the header on the left. I'm using `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}`.
Below is the header code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}            % Permits header customization. See header section below.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \lhead{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot{}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Starting Here}
Some stuff
\newpage
New stuff

\end{document}
```

I have to submit this document with specific formatting requirements and want to continue using the fancyhdr package. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117328/fancyhdr-does-not-apply-same-header-footer-on-chapter-and-non-chapter-pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your MWE loads the `fancyhdr` package, you don't actually use it for normal pages as there is no  `\pagestyle{fancy}` or similar. This means your code only customises plain pages like they are used for the first page of a chapter.

If you want to customise normal pages as well:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}            % Permits header customization. See header section below.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \lhead{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot{}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Starting Here}
Some stuff
\newpage
New stuff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is really helpful to understand latex better!

Answer (score -1):

from the .cls file, I commented \pagestyle and added following code before /begin{document}.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}            % Permits header customization. See header section below.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \lhead{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot{}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
```